# Callback function not executing click after .load()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I've come to a road block and I'm hoping someone can explain where my error is. I'll do my best to explain my script, sorry if I overly break it down.

I have a div on page1.html that is being replaced by a div on page2.html via jquery's .load(). My script which is found in the `<head>` is as following:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".info").click(function(event){

    var gallery = event.target.id;
    $("#replace").load( "folio/" + gallery + ".html #grab", function () {

      jQuery("#gallery").unitegallery({
        theme_enable_preloader: true,
        tiles_col_width: 250,
        tiles_space_between_cols: 10,
        tiles_min_columns: 1,
        tile_enable_image_effect:true,
        tile_image_effect_type: "blur",
        tile_image_effect_reverse: true,
        lightbox_show_numbers: false,
        lightbox_top_panel_opacity: true,
        lightbox_overlay_opacity:1
      });

      $("#return").on("click", function(){
            $("replace").load(" Portfolio1.html #replace1") });

    });
  });
});
</script>
```

The script executes when a `<a id="folio1" class="info">` is clicked. A variable gallery will store the id value of the `<a id="folio1" class="info">` that was clicked. I then select the `<div id="replace">` which will have its content updated via Jquery's `.load()`. Variable `gallery` that is storing the id will be used inside the `.load` to determine the appropriate page url the new content will be loaded from. So far this works perfectly.

On success of `.load()` I create a call back function which executes `.unitegallery()`. `Unitegallery()` successfully executes and beautifully creates the image gallery. After unitegallery() I have another function which is waiting using `.on("click"` for a click event on `<a id="return">`. This function will perform another `.load` that will return `<div id="replace">` back to its previous state. *This is when things stop working.*

**Note**:The selector used for the function `<a id="return">`, was inserted into the webpage via the first `.load()`.

**Issue:** This `.on("click"` is not executing.

Ideas on why that portion of the script is not executing? Is the `<a id="return">` loaded into the document by the first `.load()` not able to be selected?

Ask me questions for clarification! :)

Comment: Don't you need to specify an id parameter with '#', as in $('#replace').load(...); ?

Comment: Your missing the hash mark in your second "replace" selection

Comment: Thanks Adrian M. And Aluan Haddad! You are both correct the '#' was missing. Cant believe i missed that. Good to have a fresh pair of eyes.

Answer (score 1):

please see my comment below if it works.

```
$("#return").on("click", function(){
    $("replace").load(" Portfolio1.html #replace1") // you need the # because i think the event registration will not recognize 'replace'
    //enter code here`
});
```

Also if this does not work, can you please paste your html so we can see the structure of your document.

I also just want to point out, there is nothing wrong when the event registration will be moved outside of the load scope.

Comment: Wow... what a careless mistakes. Guess i need sleep. Thank you for your help!

Comment: glad to help, take note also of my other comment.

Comment: I did! As a clarification you are saying placing the second load outside of the first loads callback shouldnt a problem?

Comment: yes, you are just registering an event.. so that is not a problem. you can modify the registration using on.

Comment: Wonderful, I originally had it seperated but when it failed for the above reason I changed it to the above code which also failed. Now i know my simple error i will be returning it outside